# Why does dplyr use ".data" as a parameter?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the documentation for dplyr all of the data manipulation verbs have a parameter called ".data". However, most parameters in R that involve data are simply called "data". Does anyone know why dplyr uses ".data" instead of just "data"?

I've been through several sources of information and I've had no luck finding an explanation. However, I need to be able to explain to students why this is the case. So, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to the documentation for your reference:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf

Comment: Mostly just to avoid name collisions. There are some rare instances of base functions with arguments that begin with a period as well.

Comment: ...took me a while to find the example I was thinking of: `prcomp` has an argument `scale.`. There might be others if you look hard.

Comment: And `transform()`

Comment: `data` is an R function. It's considered bad practice to name your data objects with names that are also function names (and that includes names like `df`, `list`, `numeric`, `vector`  ... all of them are functions.) Hadley probably didn't want people making fun  of him :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate that there are so many functions in R with nouns as names (like "data"). However, R (and it's predecessor S) have evolved through many software development paradigms, so I guess it's to be expected.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments provided by joran, 42, and hadley (who wrote dplyr), it appears that the correct answer is to avoid name collisions with the `data()` function in the base packages in R.

It is considered a best practice to avoid name collisions, and thus the dot prefix is just an arbitrary character to disambiguate the `.data` parameter in dplyr from the `data()` function in the base R package.

Comment: I think potential collisions with the `data` function are less worrying than potential collisions/confusion with column names in the data itself.